# Kubuntu 22.04 External usb disk doesn't mount

Tags: usb, mount, kubuntu

I am trying to mount my hard drive with USB 2.5 Hard Drive Enclosure and dose nothing and outputs errors to dmesg. Kubuntu 22.04.2
This HDD works correctly when it is in laptop. I successfully installed Kubuntu without any errors. It mounts correctly with Ubuntu 22.04.2, Arch on same laptop same setup. Also I am able to mount it entering Kubuntu recovery root console.
But when I try to connect it in normal mode with Desktop environment running I get following in dmesg:

```
[ 67.366176] usb 3-5: new high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[ 67.518988] usb 3-5: New USB device found, idVendor=14cd, idProduct=6116, bcdDevice= 1.50
[ 67.518990] usb 3-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=3, SerialNumber=2
[ 67.518990] usb 3-5: Product: USB 2.0 SATA BRIDGE
[ 67.518991] usb 3-5: Manufacturer: Super Top
[ 67.518992] usb 3-5: SerialNumber: M6116018VE15
[ 67.520680] usb-storage 3-5:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 67.521098] scsi host1: usb-storage 3-5:1.0
[ 68.530635] scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access TOSHIBA MK6459GSXP PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
[ 68.530738] sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[ 68.531463] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] 1250263728 512-byte logical blocks: (640 GB/596 GiB)
[ 68.531659] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[ 68.531660] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
[ 68.531830] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[ 68.531833] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 68.586729] sdb: sdb1 sdb2 sdb3 sdb4
[ 68.586924] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[ 92.447078] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=22s
[ 92.447081] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current]
[ 92.447083] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Invalid command operation code
[ 92.447084] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 32 14 18 00 00 00 08 00
[ 92.447085] critical target error, dev sdb, sector 840177664 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 103.614516] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=11s
[ 103.614518] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current]
[ 103.614520] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Invalid command operation code
[ 103.614521] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 4a 85 82 a0 00 00 08 00
[ 103.614522] critical target error, dev sdb, sector 1250263712 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 114.781762] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=11s
[ 114.781765] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current]
[ 114.781766] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Invalid command operation code
[ 114.781768] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 32 14 18 00 00 00 08 00
[ 114.781769] critical target error, dev sdb, sector 840177664 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 114.781773] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb2, logical block 0, async page read
[ 125.948894] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=11s
[ 125.948898] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current]
[ 125.948899] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Invalid command operation code
[ 125.948900] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 32 94 18 00 00 00 08 00
[ 125.948901] critical target error, dev sdb, sector 848566272 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
```

Googling solution shows either, HDD is bad. I think my is Ok, because it working properly anywhere else but Kubuntu Desktop envirnonment. Or questions related Ubuntu, but in my case it works correctly on Ubuntu (tested on 22.04 and 20.04).

**Update. Partially solved.**

I did some more experiments. It is not working on any Plasma. KDE Neon Kubuntu 22.10.
Also my "egestar usb 2.0 external enclosure" stops working if I call smartctl -a /dev/sdc command.
So I think Plasma (or Dolphin) calls some SMART command before mounting. Gnome and other don't do this. Do what you ask for, just mount.

If I insert HDD to other case (asus) it woks correctly and also is able to response to smartctl.

Yes, I will  buy new modern case. But it will be good to know how to disable this extra SMART calls from Plasma. Or may be there is a way temporary disable any actions on usb storage connection. So I will be able to mount it manually without SMART command calls.

Comment: If it works correctly when connected inside the notebook but does not mount when in a caddy then the issue will be one of the following: (1) the caddy is bad (2) the hard drive is not receiving enough power over the USB port (3) the hard drive is not fully seated in the caddy's SATA port. Experience has shown that 95% of the time, it's the second reason. If the USB caddy does not have a dedicated power connection, consider plugging the device into a *powered* USB hub. This will increase the odds of the drive receiving the correct voltage to complete a self-check while also spinning up.

Comment: Respince to matigo. I tried to check connection (3) and power issue (2) using different cables. It always worked correctly on ubuntu but never on Kubuntu. Also it works on same installatuion but in recovery mode (without desktop environment). caddy also works on Windows 10 for ntfs partitions, This all tested on two laptops and one desktop. This is not hardware issue, or caddy.

Comment: Have you made sure that in the computer BIOS the external drive is not trying to boot?

Comment: I connect USB after boot complete. Also tested on Kubuntu 22.10 and KDE Neoin, so this is KDE feature.